# @OnSkipInWrite is Not Called in SkipListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am reading the csv file and inserting data to database using spring batch(read,process and write).I am using "jpaRepository.save" in itemWriter class to save the data into the database. And I am trying to catch the skipped item and the skipped message in @OnSkipInWrite method but this method is not called even if data are skipped. And in batch_step_execution table :
read_count = 18, write_count = 10, write_skip_count = 0, roll_back_count =8.
 Why the write_skip_count is 0? I just want to know which item was skipped and what was the exceptional message. My step :

```
@Bean
public Step step() throws IOException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").<Entity, Entity>chunk(1).reader(multiResourceItemReader())
            .processor(processor()).writer(writer()).faultTolerant().skip(Exception.class).skipLimit(100)
            .listener(new stepExecutionListener()).build();
}
```

This is my Listener class.

```
     public class StepExecutionListener{

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StepExecutionListener.class);

@OnSkipInRead
public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
    LOG.error("On Skip in Read Error : " + t.getMessage());
}

@OnSkipInWrite
public void onSkipInWrite(Entity item, Throwable t) {
    LOG.error("Skipped in write due to : " + t.getMessage());
}

@OnSkipInProcess
public void onSkipInProcess(Entity item, Throwable t) {
    LOG.error("Skipped in process due to: " + t.getMessage());
}

@OnWriteError
public void onWriteError(Exception exception, List<? extends Entity> items) {
    LOG.error("Error on write on " + items + " : " + exception.getMessage());
}}
```

Why @OnSkipInWrite and @OnWriteError is not called? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see from what you shared why the skip listener is not called but here is a self-contained example using your listener:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.OnSkipInProcess;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.OnSkipInRead;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.OnSkipInWrite;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.OnWriteError;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (Integer item : items) {
                if (item.equals(3)) {
                    throw new Exception("No 3 here!");
                }
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(5)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .skipLimit(10)
                .listener(new StepExecutionListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    public class StepExecutionListener {

        @OnSkipInRead
        public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("On Skip in Read Error : " + t.getMessage());
        }

        @OnSkipInWrite
        public void onSkipInWrite(Integer item, Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Skipped in write due to : " + t.getMessage());
        }

        @OnSkipInProcess
        public void onSkipInProcess(Integer item, Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Skipped in process due to: " + t.getMessage());
        }

        @OnWriteError
        public void onWriteError(Exception exception, List<? extends Integer> items) {
            System.err.println("Error on write on " + items + " : " + exception.getMessage());
        }}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        StepExecution stepExecution = jobExecution.getStepExecutions().iterator().next();
        System.out.println("WriteSkipCount = " + stepExecution.getWriteSkipCount());
    }

}
```

This example prints:

```
item = 1
item = 2
Error on write on [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] : No 3 here!
item = 1
item = 2
Error on write on [3] : No 3 here!
item = 4
Skipped in write due to : No 3 here!
item = 5
item = 6
item = 7
item = 8
item = 9
item = 10
WriteSkipCount = 1
```

Which means the skip listener is called when an item is skipped on write and the `writeSkipCount` is correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: best example for sprngbatch skip

Answer (score 0):

You can implement SkipListener interface instead of using @OnWriteError annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try that in your BatchConf:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public StepExecutionListener stepExecutionListener() {
    return new StepExecutionListener();
}
```

...
.skipLimit(1)
.listener(stepExecutionListener()
.build();